# setting logrotate to use UTC time

Tags: linux, logrotate, date

Is it possible to force logrotate to use UTC time for one configuration? I need the dateext to be set to UTC. I was hoping it was as simple as setting a date varible. Should I just run postrotate and mv the files to a new file name that puts the UTC time on after the fact. I'm just looking for a best practice or the most practical solution. Thanks in advance.

My cute attempt to cheap out with a setting a variable. :)

```
/var/log/bricks/*.log {
DATE=`date -u +%Y%m%d`
missingok
notifempty
copytruncate
daily
dateext
dateformat .%Y%m%d
compress
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you thought of generating two configurations and run logrotate normally for one configuration.

For the UTC configuration, run logrotate through a wrapper:

```
  #! /bin/sh
  TZ=UTC
  export TZ
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
  export PATH
  logrotate -s /var/lib/gmt-logrotate.status gmt-logrotate.cfg
  exit $?
```

By breaking them up, you can seperate the times you run each of the logrotate configurations.

Comment: Very smart. I didn't think of that. I'll look into it since it will give me a little more flexibility.

Comment: just implemented this and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: it also seems to work as a one-liner `TZ=UTC logrotate ...`.